# Solidity assembly code - calldatacopy, delegatecall

Tags: solidity, assembly, delegatecall, calldata

I have been trying to understand how assembly code works,spending lots of hours, but I could not.

**Please help me**

Basically, I am digging into a proxy contract, and I do not really understand calldatacopy and delegatecall.

Would you please explain it ?

```
fallback() external {
    bytes4 sig;
    assembly { sig := calldataload(0) }
    uint len = _sizes[sig];
    address target = _dest;

    assembly {
        calldatacopy(0x0, 0x0, calldatasize())
        let result := delegatecall(sub(gas(), 10000), target, 0x0, calldatasize(), 0, len)
        return(0, len) //we throw away any return data
    }
}
```

I do not really understand how the assembly code **delegatecall** works.

so The EIP-7 said

1. gas: the amount of gas the code may use in order to execute;
2. to: the destination address whose code is to be executed;
3. in_offset: the offset into memory of the input;
4. in_size: the size of the input in bytes;
5. out_offset: the offset into memory of the output;
6. out_size: the size of the scratch pad for the output.

so, let's assume that I deployed **"MyContract"**

I sent the msg.data **"0x360058390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"**
to the **"MyContract**"

```
0x36005839 : a function selector
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 : input value
```

However, there was no function selector for the **"MyContract"**,

So the fallback function took care of it!

```
assembly {
    calldatacopy(0x0, 0x0, calldatasize())
    let result := delegatecall(sub(gas(), 10000), target, 0x0, calldatasize(), 0, len)
    return(0, len) //we throw away any return data
}
```

I used the event to print out calldatasize() and it was 36.
I think it was because 4bytes for the function selctor + 32bytes for the input value

```
calldatacopy(0x0, 0x0, calldatasize())
```

I guess, In assembly, it will copy the exact same msg.data I sent.

**Do I clearly understand calldatacopy?**

**But what is this for ? It does not even return the value..**

```
delegatecall(sub(gas(), 10000), target, 0x0, calldatasize(), 0, len)
```

Okay, for this part, I understand gas, target address.

**But why does the in_offset start at 0 and is the in_size calldatasize?**